# Kernel test throws errors: field not found, and Base table or view not found:

Tags: 9, testing

Here's the class I want to test:

```
class Thing {
  
    public function foo() {
      return \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('body', 'blah')->execute();
    }
  
  }
```

And the test:

```
class footest extends \Drupal\KernelTests\KernelTestBase {

  public static $modules = ['node', 'user', 'field'];

 public function testFoo() {
   $thing = new Thing();
   \PHPUnit\Framework\assertEquals($thing->foo() ,4);
 }
}
```

Obviously this is not a real class or a real test, but they are pared down to the basics to demonstrate the issue.

When I run the test I get "`Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryException : 'body' not found`".

If I replace "body" with "field_baz', a field that I know exists on at least some content types, I get "`Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryException : 'field_baz' not found`".

Removing the condition entirely, so that the function body becomes:

`return \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->execute();`

produces "`Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'carbon.test65392739node' doesn't exist`"

What am I doing wrong? How can I write tests for code that uses EntityQuery? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test classes that extend `KernelTestBase` needs to create the database tables in their `setUp()` method. See [`EntityDisplayTest::setUp()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field_ui%21tests%21src%21Kernel%21EntityDisplayTest.php/function/EntityDisplayTest%3A%3AsetUp/9), for example, which creates the database tables for the Node entity.

```php
  parent::setUp();
  $this->installEntitySchema('entity_test');
  $this->installEntitySchema('node');
  $this->installEntitySchema('user');
  $this->installConfig(['field', 'node', 'user']);
```

Setting `$modules` to the required modules is not sufficient for the database tables to be created. `EntityDisplayTest` itself sets `EntityDisplayTest::$modules` to `['field_ui', 'field', 'entity_test', 'user', 'text', 'field_test', 'node', 'system']` but then calls [`KernelTestBase::installEntitySchema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21KernelTests%21KernelTestBase.php/function/KernelTestBase%3A%3AinstallEntitySchema/9) for the User and Node entities.

For database tables that are not for entities, there is [`KernelTestBase::installSchema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21KernelTests%21KernelTestBase.php/function/KernelTestBase%3A%3AinstallSchema/9), which creates the database tables a module defines in its `hook_schema()` hook.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have helped, but now I have another error: "Exception : Exception when installing config for module node, message was: No schema for system.action.node_delete_action"

Comment: It means you need to create that database table with `KernelTestBase::installConfig()`. If then the exception is referring to the configuration schema, probably that is not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling a great deal to find a way of writing automated tests for Drupal code that manipulates entities. Your answer solved the immediate issues that I asked about, but I ended up down another rabbit hole when it came to loading site config. This probably breaks the rules of stack exchange but do you offer paid help? I've noticed your name on a few Drupal testing questions so you seem to know what you are on about!